# Swift - Cells display wrong data before updating with correct data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Each cell in the cell loads and image and some text from parse.com
but when i'm scrolling it shows wrong image before the loaded image and wrong usernames. The timeago and messages works properly.

I have read about prepareForReuse() method but its not working.

Any ideas ?

UITableViewController:

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PTATableViewCell
      cell.delegate = self



        cell.setPanGesture(.LeftToRight, mode: .Exit, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), view: viewWithImage(named: "infostart"))

        cell.leftToRightAttr.triggerPercentage = 0.4
        cell.leftToRightAttr.rubberbandBounce = false
        cell.leftToRightAttr.viewBehavior = .DragWithPan


        let targetObject = rooms[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        let targetUser = users[indexPath.row] as PFUser

        let mm = rooms[indexPath.row]
        cell.mesaj.text = mm.objectForKey("Message") as! String
        cell.timeAgo.text = "\(targetObject.updatedAt!.formattedAsTimeAgo())"

    let userget = PFUser.query()
        userget!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: targetUser.objectId!)
        userget!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let fUser = objects!.last as? PFUser {
                    let namee = fUser.objectForKey("name") as! String
                    let agee = fUser.objectForKey("age") as! Int
                    cell.nameUser.text = "\(namee), \(agee)"
                    if let pica = fUser.objectForKey("dpSmall") as? PFFile {
                        pica.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                cell.userdp.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                cell.userdp.layer.borderColor = colorText.CGColor
                                circleBorder(cell.userdp)
                            }
                        })
```

Customviewcell:

```
public override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    nameUser.text = "Loading..."
    userdp.image = nil
    timeAgo.text = nil
    mesaj.text = nil
    likedtext.text = nil
    removeSwipingView()
    stateOptions = .None
    leftToRightAttr = PTATableViewItemStateAttributes()
    rightToLeftAttr = PTATableViewItemStateAttributes()
}
```

Comment: this doesn't no help you because the address of completion block is the same even you are reseting values. Lets say cell A has address: 0x01 and the completion target is A: 0x01 then you are reusing the same cell 0x01 and targeting another block but block 1 may not finished so block 1 with replace the block 2 image

Comment: is there a another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cells in the table view are reused. Since you're fetching the new image and usernames in the background, the previous contents of the cell (that is being reused) will be shown until the new content is fetched and replaced. Notice how the message and time ago is set on the cell synchronously (in this case, not inside the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` callback), which is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PFQuery has a method to cancel operation. https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)cancel

Try this.
Define query as property of PTATableViewCell

```
let userget = PFQuery?
```

and cancel operation before doing another. Something like that:

```
if cell.userget != nil {
    cell.userget.cancel()
}
cell.userget = PFUser.query()
cell.userget!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: targetUser.objectId!)
...
```

Comment: I am not sure about this. It's 02:38 here :P

Comment: its here also 2:43 usta :p will try it now

Comment: what does `usta` mean. Are you Turkish?

Comment: Google Translate auto detect :P

Comment: this will cancel the query not image loading. I suggest you to use SDWebImage

Comment: haha means master. i thought you were turkish because your name. :)

Comment: "Usta" is used also here with the same meaning 

Comment: I have to . Good night

Comment: Looks like its working now USTA :D without SDWebImage

Comment: It looks but it is not. You have to use it or control the queue by yourself which isn't a good idea.